# How to use Angular to create n printable pages?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Well, I've searched a bit and did not find anything similar.

I want to know how can I use Angular to create printable content, jump to the end of the page and print more content.

How can I force the content to always fit on a specific size, like a PDF? Do I need Angular to do this? If not HTML, can I iterate over PDF printable pages?

**Example:**

Suppose I'm a teacher and I've asked my students to send a 10 lines essays to a specific web system. Now, in the admin page, I want to print 10 students essays on 10 pages, every one of them starting on line 0 of the respective page.

**Example 2:**

Suppose I want to print n blank pages. On a system, I'm asked how many pages do I want and Angular prints it.

**Example 3:**

Suppose I have an array with 3 names. I want to print the first name on the first page, second on the second and third on the third.

**@edit**

This is the [final project](https://github.com/Rodmentou/timesheet) implemented. It's a timeSheet generator. It takes an array inside app.js and print a new page for every employee.

Comment: What you got so far?

Comment: look at phantom js as well

Comment: I've tried some time ago with an ng-repeat that would fill the remaining lines to finish the page, but this don't work if the user zooms in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply apply the appropriate CSS:

```
.pageBreak {
  page-break-after: always;
}


<p ng-repeat="essay in essays" class="pageBreak">
{{essay}}
</p>
```

Every essay will be printed on a separate page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try it in a few hours.

Comment: Hey, Zero, thank you.
This is the final project: https://github.com/Rodmentou/timesheet

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to put this as a comment, but I don't have enough rep so please excuse me. :/

Maybe not a direct answer, but I suggest you also take a look at this directive I found some time ago:

This directive lets you isolate specific parts of your page for printing.

```
app.directive('ngPrint', function () {
    var printSection = document.getElementById('printSection');
    // if there is no printing section, create one
    if(!printSection) {
        printSection = document.createElement('div');
        printSection.id = 'printSection';
        document.body.appendChild(printSection);
    }

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.on('click', function () {
            printSection.innerHTML = '';
            var elemToPrint = document.getElementById(attrs.printElementId);
            if(elemToPrint) {
                printElement(elemToPrint);
            }
        });
        window.onafterprint = function () {
            // clean the print section before adding new content
            printSection.innerHTML = '';
        }
    }

    function printElement(elem) {
        // clones the element you want to print
        var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
        printSection.appendChild(domClone);
        window.print();
    }
    return {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'A'
    };
});
```

You can define what id of element this directive will work on by specifying the `print-element-id` attribute, like so:

```
<button ng-print print-element-id="printThis">Print</button>
```

And you define the printable area by using the same id, like this:

```
<div id="printThis">
    <!--insert printable content here.-->
</div>
```

This clones all contents of the element with id of `printThis` into an element with id of `printSection`, which is appended at the end of the document. What's left to do is to hide `printSection` when you're not printing, and show only the `printSection`, hide everything else when you are.
The only other thing to remember is to include styles for printing. Mine looked like this:

```
@media screen {
    #printSection {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media print {
    body * {
        display:none;
        visibility:hidden;
    }

    #printSection, #printSection *:not(table):not(thead):not(tbody):not(tr):not(td):not(th){
        display: block;
        visibility:visible;
    }
    #printSection {
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        margin-bottom:0;
    }
    table{
        display:table;
        visibility:visible;
    }
    thead{
        display:table-header-group;
        visibility:visible;
    }
    tbody{
        display:table-row-group;
        visibility:visible;
    }
    td, th{
        display:table-cell;
        visibility:visible;
    }
    tr{
        display:table-row;
        visibility:visible;
    }

}
```

I used this in an app I've been developing, where the dashboard and UI components were interfering with the printability of the contents I wanted to print.

Credit goes to [this article.](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2014/08/09/building-a-simple-angularjs-print-directive/) I've since modified the directive, but I never would've done it without reading it.

---

As an added comment, I think what you're trying to accomplish is something out of Angular's capabilities. You can print up to n items or articles, but there's no easy way to define them as pages inside the Angular app itself. What I suggest is to use @zeroflagL's answer in conjunction with this directive.

```
<div id="printThis">
    <p ng-repeat="essay in essays" class="pageBreak>
      {{essay}}
    </p>
</div>
```

My two cents.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, I've liked your questions and answers and now you have enough reputation to comment everywhere. I'll try your answer as soon as I get home.

Comment: Thank you for that! Hope you get it figured out.